# How to calculate Determinant Matrix 2x2 -C

Tags: c, matrix

So I **need to calculate the determinant matrix on 2x2 matrix**, **simple one**..
If you can, please write the code, because i don't understand like in the other thread, it's like i'm reading an English Literature + Code..

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int x[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
int i,j,d;

for(i=0;i<=1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<=1;j++){
        printf(" %d ", x[i][j]);
    }
    printf(" \n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop to calculate the determinant of a 2x2 matrix, simply use:

```
int result = (x[0][0] * x[1][1]) - (x[0][1] * x[1][0]);
```

Comment: the loop just to show the matrix ..